# how to use git branch to commit my code without affecting mainline code

Tags: git

I was working on our current release branch "base" which is going to be released pretty soon. Last moment my feature is being pulled out and I have some un-pushed changes on the base branch. This is a big set including a huge merge of around 400 commits. Since it is being pushed, I cannot push it to base. Also, I don't want to re-do the merge.

So, I was wondering if I can do this:

from the tree that has the merged changes, branch off a new branch, say "post-release" and then push it on the repository without changing base. Is it possible? I want to prevent accidental commit to base (I saw sometimes multiple refs getting updated in one single push).

This diagram may help visualize the problem.

```
master
------------------------------------------->
    \                           
     \---release1--->            
                     \
                      \--base (releasing soon)------>
                          (I have some changes merged on a local tree 
                           based off "base" but not pushed to base)
```

Since base will be released, I don't want to push my local changes but preserve these changes in some branch(which I can push to the repo.).

Ideally, I should have started with creating a branch based off "base" branch and then later on merged it but I didn't do that.

Comment: Bit confusing: could you add a diagram of sorts showing your branching structure?

Comment: @MattGibson, thanks, edited the question with a diagram.

Answer (score 1):

First off, if all you're worried about is saving the merge, that's what `rerere` is for.

That aside, what you want to do re: "saving" your changes in a branch is easily possible.

Just `git branch my_new_branch`, then `git reset --hard base` (make sure all working-copy changes are committed first! `reset --hard` removes non-indexed changes!). Now you have two branches, the current `HEAD` being at (and following) `base`, and the second branch (`my_new_branch`) still containing your unpushed changes and tracking `base`. You may use `git merge` or `git rebase` as many times as you like to keep `my_new_branch` up to date with respect to `base` before you reintegrate it.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understand your question.  From your diagram let's try constructing a few new diagrams.  Apparently you have, in a remote shared repo:

```
[master]  * --- [possibly more commits]
           \
[release1]  * --- A --- B --- C
                   \
[base]               D --- E
```

And in your own private repo:

```
[master]  * --- [possibly more commits]
           \
[release1]  * --- A --- B --- C
                   \
[base]               D --- E
                      \
[devel]                 F --- G --- I --- J
                         \               /
                           --- H --------
```

so that the tip of branch "devel" is commit J which is a merge of FGI+H, all pointing back at D (in "base") which points back at "A" (in release1).  Now someone plans to release a "release2" that they'll make by merging ABC + DE?

If you want your "devel" branch to be based on that merge, you will just have to rebase onto the result of that merge (which does not exist yet, so you have to wait).

Or, perhaps you mean that the remote shared repo above is more or less accurate, but you *don't* have a "devel" branch of your own.  Perhaps your (local) repo commit-tree looks more like this:

```
[master]  * --- [possibly more commits]
           \
[release1]  * --- A --- B --- C
                   \
[base]               D --- E --- F --- G --- I --- J
                                  \               /
                                   --- H ---------
```

If you want it to look like this instead:

```
[master]  * --- [possibly more commits]
           \
[release1]  * --- A --- B --- C
                   \
[base]               D --- E
                            \
[devel]                      F --- G --- I --- J
                              \               /
                               --- H ---------
```

then you can start by creating a "devel" branch that hangs off commit E:

```
git branch devel E  # use the commit-ID for commit E
```

and then re-point local branch "base" to commit E:

```
git branch -d base; git branch base E # again you'll want the sha1
# or: git update-ref refs/heads/base E
```

and you're done (for now, anyway; you'll eventually still have to rebase your "devel" branch later).

---

NOTE (which I think might help a lot in understanding branches): I've put the branch labels on the left of each tree-level in my diagrams, but in fact, branch labels sit "on the right" (at the "tip" of each branch, as it were).  When you do a "git commit" on a branch, that adds a new commit, then updates the branch-tip.  I suspect most people "think about" branches as if the labels are set up once, when you do the "git branch" command, and then stay there forever—but that's not how they work.  The branch label follows the tip of the branch.  The "horizontal part" of a branch, when you look at the commit tree if it's drawn the way I have drawn them here, is something you must work out based on the commit tree structure.